# material ui Google Maps place

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to get Google Places (autocomplete field) integrated with my reactjs website styled with Material UI.
I did find this demo on Material UI documentation 
[Google Maps place](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/docs/src/pages/components/autocomplete/GoogleMaps.js)
but It didn't work for me when I did change on the input nothing change

[image: input]

[demo :](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-9iz93)

**thank you hope you get what I'm trying to explain**

Comment: if you want pretty views, try bootstrap applications

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I did forget to install lodash
it's working fine now

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-9iz93)

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look on the `Console` of that demo you'll see the error:

> Google Maps JavaScript API error: InvalidKeyMapError
>   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#invalid-key-map-error

Google Maps only works with valid API keys, the one provided by default on that demo is invalid for security purposes, you have to generate your own, it can be done here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

Comment: I did add new API key can please check the demo again its working but when I did add it to my app the input does not change the same prb on the picture

Comment: You shouldn't share publicly your API key

Answer (score 0):

Helo, try this code bellow:

```
// Imports
import React, { Component } from 'react';

// Import Search Bar Components
import SearchBar from 'material-ui-search-bar';

// Import React Scrit Libraray to load Google object
import Script from 'react-load-script';

class Search extends Component {
  // Define Constructor
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // Declare State
    this.state = {
      city: '',
      query: ''
    };

  }

  handleScriptLoad = () => {
    // Declare Options For Autocomplete
    const options = {
      types: ['(cities)'],
    };

    // Initialize Google Autocomplete
    /*global google*/ // To disable any eslint 'google not defined' errors
    this.autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      document.getElementById('autocomplete'),
      options,
    );

    // Avoid paying for data that you don't need by restricting the set of
    // place fields that are returned to just the address components and formatted
    // address.
    this.autocomplete.setFields(['address_components', 'formatted_address']);

    // Fire Event when a suggested name is selected
    this.autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', this.handlePlaceSelect);
  }

  handlePlaceSelect = () => {

    // Extract City From Address Object
    const addressObject = this.autocomplete.getPlace();
    const address = addressObject.address_components;

    // Check if address is valid
    if (address) {
      // Set State
      this.setState(
        {
          city: address[0].long_name,
          query: addressObject.formatted_address,
        }
      );
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Script
          url="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=your_api_key&libraries=places"
          onLoad={this.handleScriptLoad}
        />
        <SearchBar id="autocomplete" placeholder="" hintText="Search City" value={this.state.query}
          style={{
            margin: '0 auto',
            maxWidth: 800,
          }}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Search;
```

if you have some doubt, please follow the link:

https://medium.com/@hamzaqaisrani/using-the-google-maps-places-autocomplete-javascript-api-in-a-react-project-5742bab4abc9

Comment: I did add new API key can please check the demo again it's working but when I did add it to my app the input does not change the same prb on the picture

Comment: ur app is in the other repository? did you install the dependencies by NPM?

Comment: https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#style_autocomplete Try read this docs

Comment: I did install all the dependencies on the demo everything works fine but when I did add it to my website the input can change the same thing on the photo